# How to apply Modulus of rupture to a cylinder?

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science

I have a thick dowel (43mm diameter) of a certain timber (Tasmanian Oak), I want to use it for a chin-up bar (of all things), but I'm unsure of its strength.

The [datasheet](https://www.porta.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Product-Spec-TASMANIAN-OAK-1502.pdf) for this timber supplies a Modulus of rupture, $\sigma$ (117 MPa).

However, I see that Modulus of rupture is calculated with *rectangular* beams.

$$\sigma = \frac{3FL}{2d^2b}$$

$F$ - Downwards force;
$L$ - length;
$d$ - depth;
$b$ - breadth. Assuming a 3-point model.

How can I translate that rectangular index of flexural strength into something useful for a cylinder?

I tried being clever, replacing a rectangular area $A$ with something circular, i.e. in the denominator $2d^2b$  ->  $2d .d.w$  ->  $2dA$; $A = \pi r^2$.

$$\sigma = \frac{3FL}{2\pi (\frac{d}{2}) ^2 d}$$

But thinking about it, that's probably quite false.

- The force goes from a "line" across the top of the usual rectangular beam to a point on the circumference of the dowel
- Translating down through the circular section, that load will be resisted/supported by adjacent fibers of the wood,
- that's lateral or radial, so shear forces are much higher through the cross section (surely?)
- most reinforced at the "equator"
- decreasing down to its narrowest point (the other "pole" underneath), *exactly* at the place tensile stress is greatest.

So a quick substitution of cross-sectional area of a cylinder will not do.

Quite stumped. But not a physicist. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the modulus of rupture (flexural strength) for a circular cross-section is $\frac{F L}{\pi R^3}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-point_flexural_test)

EDIT(1/28/2021): So if the length of the bar is 0.5 m, it can withstand approximately 7300 N, so it can withstand a hockey team of 6:-)

EDIT(1/28/2020): Of course, dynamic load also needs to be taken into account.

Comment: Ah, that formula wasn't on the Modulus of rupture Wikipedia page. I didn't think to look at the test. Thanks! [*goes off to make strange proposal to a hockey team...*]